# How can I make git log to show cherry-picked commits on the same line?

Tags: git

if I run "git log --graph --oneline --branches=* --date-order" on a git repository with two branches and three shared commits I can get something like this:

```
* hash9 comment6
* hash8 comment5
* hash7 comment4
| * hash6 comment6
| * hash5 comment5
| * hash4 comment4
| * hash3 comment3
|/
* hash2 comment2
* hash1 comment1
```

Is it possible to get instead something like this?:

```
* * hash9 hash6 comment6
* * hash8 hash5 comment5
* * hash7 hash4 comment4
| * hash3 comment3
|/
* hash2 comment2
* hash1 comment1
```

Comment: I don't think so for different commit objects are created when cherry-picking which leads to different hashes. Even though the commit messages are the same, the commit objects are not.

Comment: Yes, they have different hashes but git knows they are the same commit, it is possible to get which commits are on two branches with something like branch1..branch2 as argument. I'm on the phone now so I can't put an example but it is possible so what I want can be done by hand with two different git logs. The question is, can be done in one step?

Comment: This is not exactly the answer you want. `git cherry <branch1> <branch2>` can list all the commits that are of <branch2> but not of <branch1>, following a + or a -. The - indicates there is an equivalent commit in <branch1>, most probably a cherry-picked.

Comment: @ElpieKay What I want is to use the information given by your command to simplify the git --graph by showing on a single line all the equivalent commits. Something like "* * hash1 hash2 description".

Answer (score 2):

You will have to write your own graph drawing program.  The graph drawing code in `git log` is just not this clever.

Your graph drawing program will probably need [`git cherry`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry.html) or (probably better) its lower level cousin [`git patch-id`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-patch-id.html).

It will be up to you whether to compare commit messages.  If you do, is commit a123456 a copy of commit b987654 if the message differs?  What if the difference is that one of them says `(cherry picked from commit ...)` and the other does not?  The ID in this string may not match either commit, if both are cherry-picked (one with `-x` and one without `-x`) from a third commit; that third commit may no longer be in the portion of the graph you are drawing, or even in the repository, if it has aged out and been garbage-collected (e.g., due to a rebase).

What if, from branch tip `A`, you find this commit sequence:

```
* a555555 last commit
* a444444 fourth commit
* a333333 third commit
* a222222 second commit
* a111111 first commit
* a000000 common base
```

and from branch tip `B` you find this sequence:

```
* xxxxxxx second commit
* xxxxxxx last commit
* xxxxxxx fourth commit
* xxxxxxx third commit
* xxxxxxx first commit
* a000000 common base
```

How will you show this case?  I make a lot of these sorts of chains when I start with a branch with some experimental work, and then make a new version of it and rebase it into a more sensible order before reworking specific commits.

Comment: "is commit a123456 a copy of commit b987654 if the message differs?" I was thinking that by doing "git cherry-pick" git would store the link between both commits somewhere, but it looks like it's not he case. About the disordered commits, my idea was showing all of them on the line corresponding to the first one. But seems like you are right and I will have to write my own tool if I want this :)

Comment: Yes, as you've seen, cherry-pick does not link commits.  This is the reasoning behind the "daggy fix" approach (see http://wiki.monotone.ca/DaggyFixes/): if you can fix the bug close to its origin, you can *merge* that fix to anywhere that has the bug that needs the fix, and merges *do* link commits.  (Though git's logging with merges is generally even messier, so this won't help with display issues :-) )